# AWK - Compare Two Files, Match Two Fields, Insert New Column

Tags: awk

This code is broken.  I know that its inefficient run a similar code twice to get the output, but I'm not good with AWK.

In the first run, match $1 and $2 of file1 against $1 and $2 in file2.  When there is a match, insert $3 of file1 into a $2 of file1.

In the second run, match $1 and $2 of file1 against $4 and $5 in "partial-output".  When there is a match, insert $3 of file1 into a $6 of "partial-file".

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
       NR == FNR { values[$1 FS $2] = $3; next } 
       ($1 FS $2) in values { $3 = values[$1 FS $2]}1' file2 file1 >> partial-output

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
       NR == FNR { values[$4 FS $5] = $6; next } 
       ($1 FS $2) in values { $6 = values[$4 FS $5]}1' partial-output file1
```

**File1**

```
NODE1   INT1    10
NODE1   INT2    20
NODE2   INT1    10
NODE2   INT2    20
NODE3   INT1    10
NODE3   INT2    20
NODE4   INT1    10
NODE4   INT2    20
```

**File2**

```
NODE1   INT1    NODE2   INT1
NODE3   INT1    NODE4   INT1
NODE1   INT2    NODE3   INT2
NODE2   INT2    NODE4   INT2
```

**partial-output**

```
NODE1   INT1    10  NODE2   INT1
NODE3   INT1    10  NODE4   INT1
NODE1   INT2    20  NODE3   INT2
NODE2   INT2    20  NODE4   INT2
```

**Final Output**

```
NODE1   INT1    10  NODE2   INT1    10
NODE3   INT1    10  NODE4   INT1    10
NODE1   INT2    20  NODE3   INT2    20
NODE2   INT2    20  NODE4   INT2    20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need this?

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} 
    NR == FNR {v[$1,$2] = $3; next} 
    {print $1, $2, v[$1,$2], $3, $4, v[$3,$4]}
' file1 file2
```